# Gale Shapley--man pessimal

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to use a 3x3 matrix to think about what the worst outcome is for the men in the Gale Shapley algorithm. I know that there is an outcome where each man ends up proposing to the last woman on his list...Can you assist? What order of preferences would help show this with three men and three women?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Are you talking about the ordinary Gale-Shapley algorithm, where the men propose, and the women choose the best offer they've had so far?

Comment: Yes, that algorithm! I have tried making a list of men 1,2, and 3, that prefer women a,b,c. I have been reading papers and see that the Gale Shapley algorithm worst case scenario for the men is the n^2 iterations where every man goes through his entire list, but no matter how I rank the preferences of 1,2,3,a,b,c, I can't make this happen. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the original Gale-Shapley algorithm, where the men propose to the highest-ranked woman who hasn't yet rejected them, and the women accept the best offer they've received so far, then it is impossible that each man propose to the third-ranked woman on his list.

If each man proposes to his third choice, he is rejected twice before that, so there are $6$ rejections in all, and each woman must reject two suitors.

Let the men be A,B,C and the women be a,b,c.  In the first round, if each man proposes to a different woman, the process stops, and each man gets his first choice.  If all men propose to the same woman, she chooses the one she likes best, and he gets his first choice.  We may assume therefore, that A and B propose to a, who tentatively accepts A, and that C proposes to b.

In the situation described above, the first time someone proposes to c, she will accept him, and then each woman will be holding one proposal, so the process will stop.  Therefore, even if a and b each reject two suitors, c will reject no one, and there can be no more than $4$ rejections.

Comment: So, I have the preferences for men as: 1: c>a>b 2: a>c>b 3: c>a>b and for women a: 1>3>2 b: 3>2>1 c: 2>1>3 so in the first round the men propose and c accepts 1 and a accepts 2. 3 is left with no one. 3 proposes to a in the next round, and a dumps 2 and accepts him. So now 2 must propose again in the third round to c. C dumps 1 and accepts 2. Now 1 is left to propose and proposes to a who accepts. Is this the worst the algorithm can do? I have only three rejections.

Comment: I am trying to determine what the very worst outcome is for men, the proposers, in Gale Shapley.

Comment: If A and B both rank a>b>c and C ranks b>a>c, a ranks C>A>B, and b ranks A>B>C then you get $4$ rejections, I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right! this worked! thank you so much!

Comment: If I answered your question, you should accept my answer by clicking the check mark, so that the question shows as closed.

Comment: I am new to the platform so didn't know that! Just clicked it. Thanks!